# scale div and adapt his parent size

Tags: css

I've this code : https://jsfiddle.net/56pghvt6/
I want my parent height adapt to his visible content but when I apply a `transform: scaleY(0)` to the child div. Actually parent height don't change.

precision : I use ScaleY to animate a mouse hover, so `display: none` are not a solution

Any idea to solve the problem ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `transform` doesn't affect the elements original position or size, you could also animate for example the `max-height`.

```css
.parent{
  border: 1px solid red
}
.children{
  transition: transform .3s ease-in-out, max-height 0.3s ease-in-out;
  transform-origin: 0 0;
  max-height: 300px;
}
.parent:hover .children{
  transform: scaleY(0);
  max-height: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="intro">
    <p>Hover me</p>
  </div>
  <div class="children">
    <p>text line 1</p>
    <p>text line 2</p>
    <p>text line 3</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: not perfect on parent animation but great solution ! thank's

Comment: @Fabien Thanks...and I know. Hopefully we soon will be able to animate `auto` and have the browser get the actual value on its own. If one want _perfect_ today, one need a script to get the height prior to kicking of the animation